# MS Visual Studio project requires Admin rights for debug, but not release

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Somehow I have got a VS2010 project that runs fine as a release build, but each time I try to run the debug build, it insists that I elevate to administrator. Is there a setting in Visual Studio or the registry that I can clear to restore my debug build to a sane state?

Answer (score 0):

False alarm: while experimenting with "Run as administrator" options, I had set a Linker -> Manifest File setting that required the debug build to run as administrator... and then got distracted with downstream issues. Once this was cleared, normal behaviour resumed.